# colour = discord.Colour.green() invalid syntax

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am making a discord bot via python. For an embed, I used `colour = discord.Colour.green()` but it says that's invalid syntax. Why is this? The tutorial I'm using does the exact same thing.

Comment: For an embed it should be `discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Still says invalid syntax...

Comment: Can you please provide the full code?

Comment: Sure, it's long though. Should I just post the embed code instead?

Comment: Yes, just the part where the error occurs.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed the problem. Forgot a comma.